# Besides close(), is there a way to be notified of a process's death?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver

Typically when a userspace process dies unnaturally, a driver's close() handler will be called.  Are there other ways that the driver can be notified of a process's death?

Comment: Are you spawning the process?

Comment: Nope.  All I have is the process's task_struct.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will be interested in the code of the function [do_exit()](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/kernel/exit.c#L1062). This is the function that on process death calls [exit_files()](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/fs/file.c#L428) which in turn calls the [close()](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/fs/file.c#L376) functions for the opened files.
A quick look shows that it is probably the only way for a driver to be notified of the process death.